# MySQL Copy data to another table WHERE id is the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been having difficulty transferring data from my old table to the WordPress usermeta table for the past hour or two. My query so far looks like this:

```
UPDATE bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta 
SET bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta.meta_value = customer_db.customer_table.LastName
FROM customer_db.customer_table, bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta 
WHERE customer_db.customer_table.CompanyID = bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta.user_id
AND bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

But it's a no go;

I'm trying to copy the `LastName` field from **customer_table** into the `meta_value` field on the **wp_usermeta** table, where the `CompanyID` from **customer_table** is the same as the `user_id` in the **user_meta** table.

Essentially giving everyone in the WordPress table a last name (and the same for first name).

Apologies for my bad MySQL code, but any input is greatly appreciated so I can learn for the future.

The error is:

> MySQL said: Documentation 1064 - 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM rbaukcom_rbacms.supportpassword, bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta
>   WHERE rbau' at line 3

Comment: You can't use `FROM` in `UPDATE`...

Comment: Oh? Is that a MySQL thing? I thought you could in regular SQL.. I guess it's different for MySQL then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN UPDATE`, also note that you are using different database so need to make sure that the user doing the update should have access to both of them

```
update bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta um
join customer_db.customer_table ct
on ct.CompanyID = um.user_id 
set um.meta_value = ct.user_id
where 
um.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

Comment: Oh I see! Are you using `um` and `ct` as aliases there, without the `as`? So `on` is where the ID comparison is made. Is that going to set the `um.meta_value` as the user_id WHERE last_name is? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thats correct, `as` is not mandatory. I just re-wrote your logic also note that you can move the where clause to joining clause in inner join since it would do the same. `on ct.CompanyID = um.user_id  and um.meta_key = 'last_name'`

Comment: Thank a lot! That worked exactly as it should have for this question, and I've learned a few things.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax

```
UPDATE bitnami_wordpress.wp_usermeta as t1 inner join customer_db.customer_table as t2
ON t2.CompanyID = t1.user_id
       AND t1.meta_key = 'last_name' 
SET    t1.meta_value = t2.LastName
```

Comment: This gives me a different perspective to learn from, as it's different from the other answer. Thanks for this!